# How can i show swf files on HTML Form Web Part?

Tags: html-form-web-part

I want to display my swf file on Sharepoint. Which code block that i should use?

Comment: Did you try to use page viewer web part?

Answer (score 0):

answered already:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/how-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-an-html-page

code:

```
<object width="100" height="100">
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf">
    <embed src="file.swf" width="100" height="100">
    </embed>
</object>
```